# How to specify a child component to drag its parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently working on a terminal emulator project using React and styled-components. I want to add dragging feature to the terminal. Everything is good, except one thing: I want to click and hold the title bar to drag the terminal, not somewhere else.

Here is my base component: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-http-jxxex

I don't want to use any plugins or libraries because I want to know how it works. So are there any ways to achieve this just by React and javascript? Every comments are appreciated to me.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: can you show how to implement this api into my application? I tried every thing I've known so far, but all didn't work.

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of searching, I found out the problem is that I triggered `onMouseDown` in window (globally).

In order to do this, I use a function that passed to the child component to update its parent component's states, which is `onMouseDown`, then got rid of the function in `useEffect`.

Here's my final solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-liskov-puu6g

Comment: have you seen my answer as well?

Comment: your answer worked too! But it seems too much to what I expected, which were `onMouse` events and not `onDrop` events (just cared about dragging). Yes, it worked but I didn't understand what I was doing, so that's why I didn't follow your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after **reading**  [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)
here is a **very** simplified version of d&d(the rest is up to you so please read the docs):

[link to codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-engelbart-nzgpn)

Bellow is the MDN example my answer based on:

```
    <script>
function dragstart_handler(ev) {
 // Add the target element's id to the data transfer object
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("application/my-app", ev.target.id);
 ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}
function dragover_handler(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move"
}
function drop_handler(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 // Get the id of the target and add the moved element to the target's DOM
 const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("application/my-app");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

<p id="p1" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event)">This element is draggable.</p>
<div id="target" ondrop="drop_handler(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">Drop Zone</div>
```